# Cerrar AlertDialog en Android Studio desde un botón

Tags: android, alertdialog

quería saber si me podrían explicar cómo debo cerrar el AlertDialog en android studio al terminar de ejecutar una acción.
Ahora me ejecuta cada acción pero el alertdialog sigue sin cerrarse. Éste está diseñado en xml y lo llamo desde un activity. Les comparto el código del activity, desde ya muchas gracias

```js
public void alertHorarios() {

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alerta_yaviene, null);
      final TextView txtinformacion = (TextView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.txtinformacion);

       Button btnHorarios = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.btnHorarios);
       Button btnParadas = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.btnParadas);
        Button btnCancelar = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);
        Log.e("ingreso a AlertHorarios","ingreso");

        btnHorarios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {

                miFragment=new HorariosFragment();
                FragmentSeleccionado=true;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,miFragment).commit();
                FragmentSeleccionado=false;
  <!-- acá deberia cerrarse el alertdialog -->


            }
        });
        btnParadas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {

                miFragment=new YavieneFragment();
                FragmentSeleccionado=true;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,miFragment).commit();
                FragmentSeleccionado=false;
  <!-- acá deberia cerrarse el alertdialog -->
                
            }
        });

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v ) {
<!-- acá deberia cerrarse el alertdialog -->
            }
        });


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.show();
       

    }
```

Comment: Te sugiero buscar en el sitio esta información la cual ya existe, https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cerrar+alertdialog saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declara una variable global (ósea fuera del método alertHorarios)

```
AlertDialog d = null;
```

Luego en lugar de hacer `builder.show();`
Haz el siguiente código:

```
d = builder.create();
d.show();
```

Para finalizar en los onclick donde necesitas cerrar el dialog haz:

```
d.dismiss();
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funcionó perfecto !!! Un abrazo grande

Comment: Con gusto @Luis, existe una librería que un amigo y yo estuvimos creando, de hecho hace que el AlertDialog sea un poco más sencillo de usar. No hemos agregado documentación pero tal vez te interese este es el [link](https://github.com/gtmora200/AlertDialogGeneric)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu solidaridad hermano, ahora lo veo asi aprendo un poco mas sobre el tema. Soy bastante nuevo en android y la verdad este tipo de aportes me sirven muy mucho.